# Finding probabilities from probabilty generating function

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, generating-functions

Given that I have a probability generating function for $Q$ given by $\dfrac{4s^{2}}{9-3s-2s^{2}}$, I want to find $P(Q = n)$ for $n \geq 2$. I understand that I could actually use the definition of the probability generating function and derivatives, but that seems crazy. Is there a way to turn this into a summation so I can take the coefficient possibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $2s^2+3s-9=(s+3)(2s-3)$, we have:

$$\frac{4s^2}{9-3s-2s^2}=-2+\frac{4}{s+3}-\frac{1}{s-3/2}\tag{1}$$
and now we just need to exploit:
$$\forall \alpha:|\alpha|<1,\qquad \frac{1}{1-\alpha s} = \sum_{n\geq 0} \alpha^n s^n. \tag{2}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure how to apply the Geometric sum to the result after partial fractions..

Comment: You really do not see how to apply $(2)$ to $(1)$? I wonder how basic math is taught these days. So many people try to tackle difficult problems without any knownledge on basic manipulations, that sometimes to provide a (really) useful answer is almost impossible. Anyway, $$\frac{4}{s+3}=\frac{4}{3}\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{3}}=\frac{4}{3}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n} s^n.$$ Hope that helps.